# Add an option to request access from the Team Owner

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-for-teams

As a moderator, I occasionally get announcement messages about Q&A on the special Stack Moderators team. However, when I click on the link to view a post, I get the message:

> Stack Moderators is invite only. Contact the Team owner to gain access.

There is no indication who the team owner is, or how to contact them.

Please add a function that allows me to contact the Team owner and request access to a restricted Team.

Answer (score 4):

While that would be very useful to the end-user, we cannot expose information about the owner or other members of a Team to users who are not members of the Team. Giving out information about who the owner you need to contact *is* would be a privacy breach for that person. Remember that anyone who just happened to retrieve (or guess) the URL to a Team can view that page. Even just giving you the option to send the Team owner an email would create the possibility of spamming that person's inbox with repeated requests.

We've thought about this a lot, but unfortunately, there isn't really anything we could do to improve usability for the end-user that wouldn't cause problems for the owner.

The core assumption is that a member trying to join the Team knows who the owner is and has some way to get into contact with them.

It helps if you don't think of the moderator Team specifically, but of Teams as a general product. For the typical deployment, the owner is going to be someone in your company or organization that you know how to contact.

We just happen to be using this product for the moderator Team, and we're not going to special-case the code to handle this edge case. You can simply use the "contact us" form to ask for an invite. Any member of the Community Team can also invite you, and they're often lurking in chat.

Comment: Why would you need to expose any information? I am logged on, you know who I am, you know who needs to be contacted, just put a button there and have it send the message in the background.

Comment: @JamesJenkins You're thinking of this in regards to the moderator team specifically, but Teams is a product that we just happen to be using for moderators. There is no special code we're going to implement so the moderator team can be special-cased to look up your info - it's just another team that you need to request access to like any other team.

Comment: I am thinking for all teams, the same applies, you know who needs to be contacted and you don't need to tell me who it is.  I don't use it often, but as I recall even SharePoint presents me with a button to click if I don't have access. I don't recall how it works, may or may not be email.

Comment: Sending an email could still be used to just annoy the team owner. Sorry, but there really isn't anything further we can do there without causing further problems.

Comment: This could be an option (disabled by default) that the Team owner could switch on.

Comment: I didn't know who is my team owner as well as I didn't receive any email to access, so what should I do now!?

Comment: @JL2210 If we ever get team admins requesting that as a necesaary feature, we could consider that. As far as I know, none have. Most teams don't operate on an invite-only system and instead use a company domain to grant instant access without needing to ask anyone. Unfortunately that workflow doesn't work for this specific team where a company domain isn't available for all moderators.

Comment: Simply saying "that's how teams works" isn't a very good answer. Even without compromising privacy, you could put informative text instead of making an impossible suggestion. Better yet, make sure new mods get added to the relevant group without having to apply.

Comment: @Dominic We already do that. Mods get invited when they get their diamond. Some don't join right away or miss the email. But we're getting sidetracked again into one specific team.

Comment: Trawled through my mail... Yes - I got a mail. It said: "When your moderator access has been activated, you will have access to the moderator-only chat room". There was a link, but honestly this wasn't  sufficient of a call-to-action. There was no indication that I should later refer back to the mail to find the access link, or that it would be difficult to figure out. And no - we're not getting sidetracked. The question is clearly about moderators.

Comment: @DominicCronin The Teams invitation is sent separately, and isn't related to the chat room.

Comment: I'm a mod of OpenData and I also have this issue. I'm curious why this question was migrated from meta.StackExchange to meta.StackOverflow. Does that have to do with why I can't access the Teams page, because it's only for StackOverflow mods?

Comment: @philshem It was migrated here because it was requesting a feature change for Teams as a general product. If you need access, you can simply reach out via the contact form.

Comment: @animuson I'm directed to the Teams page from the Announcement section of the Mod Messages (♦️) dropdown. I don't see any contact form there, or at the Mod Dashboard or the Stack Moderators Team page.

Comment: @philshem [Our contact form](/contact)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also in this situation. As described in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390452/add-an-option-to-request-access-from-the-team-owner/390453?noredirect=1#comment735352_390453), mods can ask for access to the Stack Moderators Team site by using the generic StackExchange contact form:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

---

*update*: it worked! I'm in!